# How to keep floated width of divs to stay exact instead of 100%?

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/qEzaNr

I have 2 columns, the first column on top `section.tags-panel` Is the column I'm trying to fix. I don't want the `tag`'s to float like that until something else happens.

However I also need the default column width to be `240px`. In order for me to create that pill button style feel, I had to put in `float:left`.

^ Thus this creates a problem where I have the pill tags looking correct, but floating wrapping when they should be lined up in a single column.

The column below `section.tags-panel2` is the look I'm trying to achieve, however I'm cheating because I'm shrinking the width of the panel. The text in the tag pills should never wordwrap too.

[image]

How would you achieve this without it looking like: 
[image]

CSS:

```
 section.tags-panel {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}

section.tags-panel li { margin-right: 10px; }

.tag {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could add

```css
clear: both;
```

to the tags? This should separate them and keep them in a vertical line as no floating elements are allowed on the left or the right side of the div you specify to have the clear attached to.

Comment: Thanks! Been in JavaScript too much, starting to miss basic CSS